# get some data from string python

Tags: python, string, list

I have a string like:

```
u'c-100001,e-100001,e-100011,e-100009'
```

I want to get value like

```
[100001,100011,100009]
```

I tried:

```
l = note_to.split('-')
k = length(l)
j=[]
for i in (0,k):
   if k!==0 & k%2!= 0:
      j.append(l[i])
```

I mean I used loop.

Comment: Did you mean you wanted *unique* values or only those starting with `e-`?

Answer (score 1):

Use a list comprehension with `str.startswith` and `str.split`:

```
>>> s = u'c-100001,e-100001,e-100011,e-100009'
>>> [int(x.split('-')[1]) for x in s.split(',') if x.startswith('e-')]
[100001, 100011, 100009]
```

If you want all the items not just that start with `e-` then remove the `if x.startswith('e-')` part.

```
>>> [int(x.split('-')[1]) for x in s.split(',')]
[100001, 100001, 100011, 100009]
```

In you want only unique items then pass the list to a `set()` or use set with a generator expression.

Comment: Why the assumption that only `e-` values are to be included?

Comment: @MartijnPieters Because of OP's expected output: `[100001,100011,100009]`

Comment: But he could have wanted to get unique values only.

Answer (score 0):

Split your string on the comma and use a list comprehension:

```
[int(el[2:]) for el in note_to.split(',') if el.startswith('e-')]
```

I'm assuming you wanted to only get values that start with `e-` here; you need to clarify your question if you wanted something different.

Because we already determined that the element starts with `e-`, getting the integer value is as simple as skipping the first 2 characters.

Demo:

```
>>> note_to = u'c-100001,e-100001,e-100011,e-100009'
>>> [int(el[2:]) for el in note_to.split(',') if el.startswith('e-')]
[100001, 100011, 100009]
```

If you wanted to get *unique* values only, and order doesn't matter, use a set, and use `str.rpartition()` to split off the starting string (which could be longer than 2 characters or missing altogether, perhaps):

```
set(int(el.rpartition('-')[-1]) for el in note_to.split(','))
```

You can always turn that back into a list, based on your exact needs.

Demo:

```
>>> set(int(el.rpartition('-')[-1]) for el in note_to.split(','))
set([100001, 100011, 100009])
>>> list(set(int(el.rpartition('-')[-1]) for el in note_to.split(',')))
[100001, 100011, 100009]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it as follows:

```
string = 'c-100001,e-100001,e-100011,e-100009'
your_list = string.split(',e-')[1:]

>>> your_list
[100001,100011,100009]
```

Comment: @MartijnPieters, Because that is how the OP has specified it in the question